# How to connect with AWS mysql server using commandline?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS EC2 and I wanted to connect the Mysql to upload an sql file.

I used bitvize sftp to upload the files and with this ftp i have a commandline window to work around the server.

Here i am trying to connect the mysql using commands like -

Verify that mysql server is up and running first by a '**ps -ef | grep mysql**'

```
ec2-user 22352 254217  0 10:58 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
root     223349     1  0  2016 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --basedir=/usr --user=mysql
mysql    223349  226349  0  2016 ?        00:33:26 /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Then i tried the command **/usr/bin/mysql -uroot -p**

it prompts the password.But i don't know the password or am i doing the correct method?

The bottom line is i need to create a db and user and upload an sql file for that DB.

How could i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the root user doesn't have a password, then don't use the `-p` option.